# Prestashop 1.7 classic theme lose layout settings

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

When I change settings in classic theme, index layout from full width to 2 columns its works fine. But when i change something else, or clear cache, all theme layout settings go back to default. Maybe its not only classic problem. Any idea how I can change layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bug, still not resolved by presta, but if you want to change it now, i just realized that editing theme config will give you this possibility:

classic/theme/config/theme.yml

```
theme_settings:
  default_layout: layout-full-width
  layouts:
    index: layout-left-column
    category: layout-left-column
    best-sales: layout-left-column
    new-products: layout-left-column
    prices-drop: layout-left-column
    contact: layout-left-column
```

i added "index" for example. You can get layout key from theme layout settings.